# How can I enforce IIS 8.5 Web Deploy to use SSL (HTTPS) Only

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl, visual-studio-2013, webdeploy

I've just set-up a website on Windows 2012 (IIS 8.5).

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, and I'm wanting to configure Web Deploy so that our developers can only deploy over SSL (HTTPS).

In the website settings I've configured the SSL for the site;

[image]

For the website binding, I only have HTTPS present;

[image]

However it seems that I can still publish using WebDeploy over HTTP and I can browse to the site using HTTP, even though the file in this case wasn't found.

[image]

My main requirement is to stop developers being able to publish over HTTP.  How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try to redirect all HTTP Requests towards HTTPS

URL rewriting in IIS 7+:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2013/05/23/http-to-https-redirects-on-iis-7-x-and-higher.aspx

Comment: I have now added the HTTP binding, and I get a correct 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied response.  But I can still publish using WebDeploy over HTTP....

Comment: I think you can't enforce HTTPS when deploying your WebSite using WebDeploy. Just the settings in IIS should be enough. 
My advice would be to use a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS instead of a 403.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you don't have another IIS web site (usually the Default Web Site) that binds to port 80 with All unsigned IP address and no host header. That kind of site is a "catch-all" site that gives you the 404.